# Mouse Out Orange Div "CurrentHeight" is not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[old demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/w2j1g8ap/)**

[***Latest DEMO intermadiate issue***](http://jsfiddle.net/w2j1g8ap/23/)

On Hover iam calculating current height of the div and adding 50px through jquery.
on MouseOut current height is not applying

for example:

currentHeight = 20px (this height will be dynamic)

AddHeight = 50px

so the div will be 70px on mousehover

when i mouseOut currentHeight should be same i.e., 20px (this height will be dynamic)

**JS CODE :**

```
txt__mouse__hover : function(){
                $(".itemMasTxt").hover(function () {
                    currentHeight = $(this).height();
                    addHeight = 50;
                    $(this).animate({
                        height:(currentHeight + addHeight)
                    }, 200);


                }, function () {            
                    alert(" --" + currentHeight)    
                    $(this).animate({
                        height:(currentHeight)
                    }, 200);
                });
```

Comment: It is working in my browser.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/w2j1g8ap/29/

Answer (score 3):

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/w2j1g8ap/20/)

```
   var counter = 0;
   $(".itemMasTxt").hover(function () {
          if(innterText !== $(this)[0].innerText){
                counter = 0;
          }
          if(counter == 0){
               innerHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
               innerHeightAdd = $(this).innerHeight() + addHeight;
               innterText = $(this)[0].innerText;
          }
          counter++;
          $(this).stop().animate({
            height:(innerHeight + addHeight)
          }, 200);

    }, function () {
          $(this).stop().animate({
                height:(innerHeightAdd - addHeight)
          }, 200);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

***JS***

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){

        var container = document.querySelector('.masonry-container');
        var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: '.itemMas',
        columnWidth: 15,
        gutter : 1
        });



        var masonrySupport = ({
            large__videos__support : function(){
                $('.masonry-container .largeRec').find('.itemMasVideo').parent().addClass('item_largeRec_video_height');
            },
            smallRec__videos__support : function(){
                $('.masonry-container .smallRec').find('.itemMasVideo').parent().addClass('item_smallRec_video_height');
            },
            smallSquare__videos__support : function(){
                $('.masonry-container .smallSquare').find('.itemMasVideo').parent().addClass('item_smallSquare_video_height');
            },
            largeSquare__videos__support : function(){
                $('.masonry-container .largeSquare').find('.itemMasVideo').parent().addClass('item_largeSquare_video_height');
            },
            txt__mouse__hover : function(){
                $(".itemMasTxt").hover(function () {
                    currentHeight = $(this).height();
                    console.log(currentHeight);
                    addHeight = 50;
                    $(this).animate({
                        height:(currentHeight + addHeight)
                    }, 200);


                }, function () {            
                    console.log("2 - - - " + currentHeight) 
                    $(this).animate({
                        height:(addHeight)
                    }, 200);

                });


                },
            init : function(){
                this.large__videos__support(),
                this.smallRec__videos__support(),
                this.smallSquare__videos__support(),
                this.largeSquare__videos__support(),
                this.txt__mouse__hover()
            }
        })
        masonrySupport.init();


    })
})(jQuery);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w2j1g8ap/8/)

***CSS***

```
.itemMasTxtPara {
 padding:15px !important;   \\For saving time i made it important but u select the appropriate class and remove it
}

.itemMasTxt{
    padding:0px !important;  \\For saving time i made it important but u select the appropriate class and remove it
}
```

> Note padding to the Div was causing the problem.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w2j1g8ap/21/)

Comment: Example please in a fiddle. so that i can helpout